# How to detect Xamarin Forms System Theme Change

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to detect Xamarin Forms System Theme Change from Light to Dark ??

I have detected the App Theme change but how can I detect the change of whole operating/device theme change ?

I am using :

```
Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the docs  [react to theme changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes#react-to-theme-changes) you can achieve it by handeling the event `Application.RequestedThemeChanged`

```
Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, a) => { 
    switch(a.RequestedTheme) {
        case OSAppTheme.Dark:
            //do something
            break;
        case OSAppTheme.Light:
            //do something
            break;
        case OSAppTheme.Unspecified:
            //do something
            break;
    }
};
```

Additional flag in order to work for Android

```
[Activity(..., ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.UiMode...
```

> To respond to theme changes on Android you must include the ConfigChanges.UiMode flag in the Activity attribute of your MainActivity class.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently checking my IOS app is there something that I need to do on AppDelegate class ?

Comment: According to docs no, only Android has that specific activity flag that needs to be added if not already there.

Comment: I have already did your code bro, but it did not work when I have change the system appearance to dark nothing change and also I have overrided the onResume method and the requested theme changed event was not fired.

Comment: Emulator or real device ? Android or iOS ? Which version?

Comment: I am using Emulator

Comment: @MohammadAbuSubha Some  requirements must be met for Xamarin.Forms to respond to a system theme change: **Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.967 or greater, iOS 13 or greater, Android 10 (API 29) or greater, UWP build 14393 or greater, macOS 10.14 or greater.**

Comment: Thanks bro, I have already updated the packages.

Comment: @MohammadAbuSubha So you have solved your problem now?

Comment: nop the issue was not resolved I don't why I cannot detect the system them the Application.Current.RequestedTheme keeps returning Light

Comment: @MohammadAbuSubha Maybe you can provide your sample at github, we can download your sample to test. Because I use `Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged`, it can detects system theme changed when I change dark or light theme.